# Heroku addons confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was looking at several Heroku addons like Airbrake, WebSolr. Whats the advantage of buying these services as addons on Heroku vs just paying for these services separately on their respective websites.

Will Heroku prevent me from connecting to these services, if I dont use addons?

Comment: it's a good thing to checkout some of the 'direct' offerings too. With Heroku you tie it to a single application but if you for example go direct to sendgrid and sign up you could use the same plan across multiple apps and have higher limits that through Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it won't.  Heroku provides these addons so as to streamline your development/deployment experience.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is perhaps ease of configuration and simplified billing (some services may be cheaper as well). No, Heroku will in no way prevent you from using the services they offer outside of the Heroku interface.