# Can Heroku add-on configs change randomly in the cloud?

Tags: heroku

Being new to Heroku, I'm a bit [confused with add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843874/heroku-addons-confusion) myself.

This [Heroku blog post](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/6/28/the_new_heroku_4_erosion_resistance_explicit_contracts/) from about a year ago cites using add-ons' environment variables as a best practice:

> Your app reads config for backing services such as the database, memcached, or the outgoing SMTP server from environment variables (e.g. `DATABASE_URL`), rather than hardcoded constants or config files. This allows the platform to easily connect add-on resources (when you run `heroku addons:add`) without needing to touch your code.

I'm indeed using environment variables (via Heroku config), but in one case, I'm using my own vars instead of the default one that gets added by an add-on.

(Specifically, I prefer to use e.g. `CACHE_HOST`, `CACHE_PORT`, etc. for my Redis cache over Heroku's `REDISTOGO_URL`. It feels both more precise/modular and more generic -- esp. when I use a local instance of Redis, not RedisToGo, during development.)

I'm wondering, is that a bad practice? Could add-on configs like `REDISTOGO_URL` change randomly in the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lead engineer from the Heroku Add-ons team here. To answer you question and your other points and reasoning:

- Could the add-on config change? Yes. Add-on providers can change it at any time without warning. We recommend providers don't change it unless they absolutely have to as it will cause a restart of your app and processes. But it can change, so you should assume it will.
- More precise/modular. There's already an established standardized way of defining a pointer to a resource, a URI. And we recommend providers use this wherever possible.
- More generic, especially for local development. Yep. We recognize this is a problem. We're discussing different ways to address it, in the interim I'd recommend using foreman and a .env file.

Hope that helps. Let me know if there is anything else,

Glenn

Comment: It's great to get a thorough answer straight from the source — thanks so much. Re: the last point, I'm indeed using foreman and an .env file locally; it's just strange having my code rely on a config called `REDISTOGO_URL` -- that implies that the code requires the Redis database to be provided by RedisToGo, which feels a bit silly. Perhaps there could be an option to "rename" add-on configs / "map" them to different names?

Comment: Agreed it is weird and probably undesirable. We're considering better ways to address it. Stay tuned :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. =) I can't wait.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the point of config variables. Should/If/When a addon provider/Heroku needs to change it's variables it is able to do so without having to have you update any of your codebase. Obviously it does require your intervention if you choose to split out variables into your own as per your `REDISTOGO_URL` variable but on the whole I think it's a good design.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. Does that actually happen in practice? / Has Heroku changed env variables without notice before?

Comment: In almost 3 years of using Heroku I've never seen it happen (to my knowledge)